# How to extract city state zip-code from address string?

Tags: php, jquery, string

I am trying to extract city, state, zip-code from data string & insert in to respective columns in database.

Data string like: "Ventures/Beistle 1 Beistle Plaza Shippensburg, PA 17257".

Guide me with right solution to solve this problem.

I have already tried with below code : 
And Getting result: PA 17257

```
$string = "Ventures/Beistle 1 Beistle Plaza Shippensburg, PA 17257";

function extract_zipcode($string) {
  $zipcode = preg_match("/\b[A-Z]{2}\s+\d{5}(-\d{4})?\b/", $string, $matches);

  return $matches[0];

}

echo extract_zipcode($string) . ' ';
```

I expecting the output be like :

```
Array ( ['city'] => Ventures/Beistle ['state'] => 1 Beistle Plaza  [country] => Shippensburg ['zipcode'] => PA 17257 )
```

Comment: most simple would be using using `explode(',', trim($string));`

Comment: What you also can do is making a tables with known cities, states, zip-codes in your country then you know how to parse with string with matching or replacing..

Comment: See mine last comment, then i also does not never where the data is in the string, and you wil have te make a country table with know zipcodes or use Google maps api to get those information..

Comment: Raymond, what if there is no choice, need to extract details from same type of address string .

Comment: explode is the best option to get. if you have same format for all addresses

Comment: This is a good reason why you don't let users fill in stuff randomly.

Comment: *"what if there is no choice"* There is always atleast one, i advice you use Google Map API to get the country, state from the string *"VirVentures/Beistle, Shippensburg, 1 Beistle Plaza PA 17257"*

Comment: @RaymondNijland: but he must need API key to use google api, which is paid.

Comment: really? @devpro is the Google Geocoding API now a paid service? i didn't know that..

Comment: yeah right , and google api's  are paid and please everyone recheck the string its (" VirVentures/Beistle 1 Beistle Plaza Shippensburg, PA 17257")

Comment: @RaymondNijland: google it , you can get the answer bro $200 per month :)

Comment: @devpro don't call me bro please, *"google it "* also Google API are generally free also Geocoding API also was free in the past, that's why i mentioned the  Geocoding API before i knew it was a paid service..

Comment: @RaymondNijland: yes that was past

Comment: @devpro it was to be expected that Google might charge money for it... Topicstarter https://www.openstreetmap.org or https://www.geonames.org (Valve (steam) also uses it) also might be mature enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simplified with j query like:

```
 var my_addr_select  = 'Ventures/Beistle 1 Beistle Plaza Shippensburg, PA 17257';
    var a = my_addr_select.split(',');
            var b = [];
            var c = [];
            for (var i = 0;i<a.length; i++) {
                if(i == 0){
                    b = a[i].split('/');
                    for (var k = 0;k<b.length; k++) {
                        if(k == 1){
                        c[1] = b[k].split(' '); 
                        var addressname = c;
                        }else{
                        c[0] = b[k];
                        var user_a = c;
                        }
                        var otheraddress = c;
                    }
                }else{
                    c[2] =  a[i].split(' ');
                }
            }
            console.log(c);
            var addressFinalArray = [] ;
            for (var l =0 ;l<c.length; l++) {
                if(jQuery.isArray(c[l])){
                    var shipArray  = c[l];
                    for(m = 0;m<shipArray.length; m++){
                        addressFinalArray =addressFinalArray.concat(shipArray[m]);
                    }
                }else{
                    addressFinalArray = addressFinalArray.concat(c[l]);
                }
            }
            console.log(addressFinalArray);
```

and output from first console is:

```
["Ventures", Array(5), Array(3)]
```

and 2nd console(multidimensional array):

```
["Ventures", "Beistle", "1", "Beistle", "Plaza", "Shippensburg", "", "PA", "17257"]
```

and thus used above result for my requirement.